# Probability and the Monty Hall problem

Tags: probability, monty-hall

In this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob_comb/dependent_events_precalc/v/monty-hall-problem) is explained that during the Monty Hall problem you have a $\frac {2}{3}$ probability of winning if you always switch and a $\frac {1}{3}$ probability of winning if you never switch.

I understand the reasoning but it just feels wrong. Because if we can assume that the host always shows a goat after the first try, which implies that there are just 2 options left, you could still choose both options by switching or not.

Doesn't that conclude that there is always a $\frac {1}{2}$ probability of winning?

Comment: It does "feel" wrong, but feelings are sometimes a poor substitute for reasoning. This is one of those times. There are lots of explanations on the web (you found one). You're unlikely to get a genuinely new explanation as an answer here. You could start at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Comment: @EthanBolker I understand, but I do not get why the probability is not $\frac {1}{2}$ if you look at it this way. I hope someone could explain this.

Comment: There are indeed two options left. But they are not _equally likely_ to win.

Comment: Two choices doesn't mean two equally-likely choices.

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate or that the answers to the other question address the question asked here: Does choosing at random lead to $P(\text{winning})=\frac 12$? The answers to the other question show that the two remaining doors have probabilities of $\frac 23$ and $\frac 13$ of concealing the prize, not _equal_ probability. But, _equal_ probability is _not_ the issue. Choosing one of the two doors at random leads to $P(\text{winning})=\frac 12$ _regardless_ of the $\frac 23$, $\frac 13$ result: _any_ $p, 1-p$ will give the same $\frac 12$ for $P(\text{winning})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation that *choosing at random (with probability $\frac 12$ each) whether to switch or stay put* gives a probability $\frac 12$ of
winning the prize is perfectly correct.

Let $A$ be the event that your first choice is indeed the door that
conceals the prize. Then, $P(A) = \frac 13$ and $P(A^c) = \frac 23$.
Note that $A^c$ is the event that one of the two doors *not chosen*
conceals the prize. Once one unchosen door has been opened, you flip
a fair coin and switch or stay put according as the coin shows
Heads or Tails.  If $W$ is the event that you win the prize, then

\begin{align}
W &= (A, T) \cup (A^c, H)\\
P(W) &= P(A)P(T) + P(A^c)P(H)\\
&= \frac 13\times \frac 12 + \frac 23\times \frac 12\\
&= \frac 12.
\end{align}

The "always switch" strategy can be put into this framework by
using a **double-headed** coin that always turns up Heads, leading
to

\begin{align}
P(W) &= P(A)P(T) + P(A^c)P(H)\\
&= \frac 13\times 0 + \frac 23\times 1\\
&= \frac 23
\end{align}

and similarly for the "always stay put" strategy, the chances
of winning are $\frac 13$. I leave it
to you as an exercise to figure out what the probability of
winning is if you choose to toss a *biased* coin that turns
up Heads with probability $p, 0 < p < 1$
and to show that this probability is smaller than the probability
of winning with the $p = 1$ "always switch" strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Rework the problem with 100 doors and 99 goats.  You pick a door, the host then opens 98 doors you didn't pick all with goats.  So of the original 100 doors only two are left, the door you picked and a door the host went through a bit of effort not to open.

So how does this feel?  Now to me, I *know* when I pick one door at random out of 100 I'm going to get a bad door.  I'm not that lucky.  So I know the host is going to open all the other goat doors and leave the prize door closed.  So should I switch.  Of course, I only had a 1 in 100 chance of picking the correct door in the first place so there is a 99 in 100 chance that the goat was behind another door.  Whatever door it was was the door the host kept closed.  So there is a 99 in 100 chance that the prize is behind the other door.

The trick is to realize this *isn't* the probability of the prize being in a specific other door (the door *wasn't* specified).  It's the probability the the prize wasn't behind your door.